# Htaccess add word to URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

htaccess Expert Needed ???

How to make URL like this

**Before :** 
    zohaibbadarpura.com/anypage

**After :**
zohaibbadarpura.com/eng/anypage ?

I tried many thing but could find any to make this possible with simple because I am not expert at "htaccess" Thanks in advance.

Tried

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule /? eng/ [R=301,L] # Force people to the "eng" folder 
  RewriteRule eng/?$ index.html # Make "eng" load the index
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Force people to the "eng" folder
RewriteRule !^eng/ /eng%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```

Comment: it will add /eng/ to everypage on site?

Comment: Yes it will add `/eng/` to every page.

Comment: yes it doesn't matter whether `/eng` exists or not it will be added in the URI. Of course you need to have further rules to handle all `/eng/anything` URIs

Comment: your Code wants /eng/ directory in real..... just want to fake it want else I should write?

Comment: Hmm then your question text (before, after) was confusing. Try edited code.